# An array with diagonal arrows

Tags: arrows, arrays

[image]I have any array which I would like to consider two cases from it so to write it firstly then to consider two diagonal arrows lead to two vertical arrays.

I wrote the above but

```
$$x = \left( {\begin{array}{c}
   x_1 \\
   x_2 \\
   x_3  \\
   \vdots \\   
   x_n \\
   \end{array} } \right) \nearrow y_1 =
  \left( {\begin{array}{c}
   y_1 \\
   y_2 \\ 
   y_3 \\
  \vdots \\   
   y_n \\
    \end{array} } \right) \searrow y_2 =
  \left( {\begin{array}{c}
   y_1 \\
   y_2 \\ 
   y_3 \\
     \vdots \\   
   y_n \\
    \end{array} } \right)$$
```

As you see in the picture that y_1 and y_2 are not vertical! How could I bring y_2 below y_1.

P.S: I am interested to solve this problem without using tikZ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For *very simple* arrows one may use the `\vector` macro provided by the LaTeX kernel. The syntax is

```
\vector(x,y){length}
```

where `x` and `y` are integers between -4 and 4 which specify the direction, and the length is given in `\unitlength` (predefined 1pt).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

With \verb+\nearrow+/\verb+\searrow+
\[
x = \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{pmatrix}
\begin{aligned}
\raisebox{-2\height}{$\nearrow$\quad} & y_1 = \begin{pmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \\ y_3 \\ \vdots \\ y_n \end{pmatrix} \\[1ex]
\raisebox{2\height}{$\searrow$\quad}  & y_2 = \begin{pmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \\ y_3 \\ \vdots \\ y_n \end{pmatrix}
\end{aligned}
\]

With \verb+\vector+
\[
x = \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{pmatrix}
\vcenter{\vbox{\hbox{\vector(2,3){15}}\hbox{\vector(2,-3){15}}}}\quad
\begin{aligned}
y_1 &= \begin{pmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \\ y_3 \\ \vdots \\ y_n \end{pmatrix} \\[1ex]
y_2 &= \begin{pmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \\ y_3 \\ \vdots \\ y_n \end{pmatrix}
\end{aligned}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Some cosmetic changes to your code

- [Why is `\[...\]` preferable to `$$...$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/82917)
- I use the `pmatrix`  environment from `amsmath`.

Comment: thanks for the great answer. Using the second solution, is there a possibility to control the size? by the way, I modified the sentence :)

Comment: @Jean Give a look at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Picture#Arrows

Answer (score 1):

You could realize your diagonal arrows for the three matrix using `tikz-cd` package typical for commutative-diagrams or `xy` package that it has another structure than tikz-cd but that it generates the same result. Being `tikz-cd` as a big matrix `[row sep=-.62in,column sep=.5in]` inform you that the distance of the rows and the columns. In the package's documentation you can finded further explanations in this way.

[image]

```
%% Compile and read me!
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=-.62in,column sep=.5in]
& y_1 = \begin{pmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \\ y_3 \\ \vdots \\ y_n \end{pmatrix} \\
x = \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{pmatrix} \arrow[ru] \arrow[rd] &\\
& y_2 = \begin{pmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \\ y_3 \\ \vdots \\ y_n \end{pmatrix}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Sincerely my code is *off-topic* with the tags that you have chosen.